# Best way for bulk load of data into SQL Server with Python without pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to load data from our cloud environment (pivotal cloud foundry) into SQL Server. Data is fetched from API and held in memory and we use tds to insert data to SQL Server, but only way in documentation I see to use bulk load is to load a file. I cannot use pyodbc because we dont have odbc connection in cloud env.

How can I do bulk insert directly from dictionary?

pytds does not offer bulk load directly, only from file

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to convert the data into bulk insert sql.  Similar to how you migrate mysql.
Or if you could export the data into cvs, you could import use SSMS (Sql Server Managment Studio).